# NetBeans error building Maven project: "InputOutput doesn't support folding"

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I updated my NetBeans version and now I can't build any Maven projects. Normal Java projects build fine. For example, when I create a new project and try to build it, I get:

> "unexpected exception"
>
> "The InputOutput doesn't support folding".

The stack trace starts with...

> org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)

...and ends with...

> org.openide.windows.IOFolding.startFold(IOFolding.java:143).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with TMCBeans 0.9.1. installation of Netbeans. At least one other person is having the same problem with the same version of TMCBeans. Normal installation of (regular) Netbeans fixes the problem.